# Where does ResourceBundle.getBundle("ResourceFile", new Locale("us", "US")) look for the file?

Tags: java, localization, resourcebundle

I'm running Eclipse and trying to create a simple test program trying our ResourceBundle with a couple of different files. The file is properly named as ResourceFile_us_US.properties. But I'm getting an exception on the getBundle() call because it apparently can't find the file. Where should it be located so it can be found?

Answer (score 18):

You know java is looking for a properties file in a specific locale.  You may be baffled why java keeps complaining it can't find a properties file that is right there.  A few things to keep in mind when debugging this type of errors:

1. These resource properties files are loaded by classloader, similar to java classes.  So you need to include them in your runtime classpath.
2. These resources have fully-qualified-resource-name, similar to a fully-qualified-class-name, excerpt you can't import a resource into your java source file.  Why? because its name takes the form of a string.
3. `ResourceBundle.getBundle("config")` tells the classloader to load a resource named `"config"` with default package (that is, no package).  It does NOT mean a resource in the current package that has the referencing class.
4. `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.cheng.scrap.config")` tells the classloader to load a resource named `"config"` with package `"com.cheng.scrap."`  Its fully-qualified-resource-name is `"com.cheng.scrap.config"`

More : [Can't find bundle for base name com...config, locale zh_CN](https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/p_java_util_missingresourceexception_can)

Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

If you create a package `resources` and put the file `hello_en_US.properties`
 inside it, which has the content:

> hello = Hello World!!

you can print the content of hello using the following code:

```
package localization;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ResourceBundleDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Locale en_US = new Locale("en", "US");
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.hello", en_US);

    // print the value of the key "hello"
    System.out.println("" + bundle.getString("hello"));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of two:

1. `/src/resources`
   Make sure you include locale in name of resource bundle file. e.g for Zimbabwe, it will be `ResourceBundle_en_ZW.properties` and you would load it as `ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBunndle("ResourceBundle", Locale.getDefault());`
2. In your classpath. Make sure the classpath environment variable is set

Answer (score 1):

I believe it just looks in the classpath.